# Tmux bind-key not working for split-window

Tags: tmux

I have following configuration in my tmux config file:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-s

bind-key - split-window -v
bind-key \ split-window -h
```

When I am in tmux, if I try

```
Ctrl+s : split-window -v
```

it works. If I try

```
Ctrl+s -
```

it does not work. It says No Buffer, and tmux does not do anything.

Any help on how can I debug this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

The `-` key is already bound to the `delete-buffer` command. You can check this by executing `tmux list-keys`. You must unbind it and then apply your binding:

```
unbind -
bind-key - split-window -v
```